# Limit of function - non existence

Tags: calculus, limits

Show that the following limit does not exist:

$$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{3x^4-8x^3+5}{x^3-x^2-x+1}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can factorize the expression as follows:
$$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{3x^4-8x^3+5}{x^3-x^2-x+1} = \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{(x - 1)(3x^3 - 5x^2 - 5x - 5)}{(x - 1)^2(x + 1)} = \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{3x^3 - 5x^2 - 5x - 5}{(x - 1)(x + 1)}$$

Now consider the two limits from the sides:
$$\begin{align}\lim_{x \to 1^-}\frac{3x^3 - 5x^2 - 5x - 5}{(x - 1)(x + 1)} = +\infty\\
\lim_{x \to 1^+}\frac{3x^3 - 5x^2 - 5x - 5}{(x - 1)(x + 1)} = -\infty
\end{align}$$

Since they're different the limit does not exist.